# Split parts from a regular sized image sheet into separate images with JS

Tags: javascript, image, base64, blob

I am trying to display parts from an image sheet into separate images.

There's a way to do it with CSS, as in how Reddit Flairs work on the old version of Reddit.

Below is an image that acts as a sheet. I am going to call it `unicode_page_00.png`

[image: 1]

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div style="background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxJOx.png); image-rendering: pixelated; width: 64px; height: 64px; background-size: 1024px; background-position: -64px 0px;">
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxJOx.png">
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ztpr5cq/1/

The first part displays an image taken from the image sheet. For this example, the sheet is 256x256 pixels and each character is 16x16 pixels.

I took it and zoomed it in by 4. So the first image shows as 64x64. Then I've shifted the position to display the second character on the sheet from left to right.

And below is the entire image sheet for demonstration.

This is done with CSS. **The issue is that you can not save the image the way it was cropped and modified with CSS**. Even if it would be made possible with CSS, it would take the entire image sheet and save that instead.

I am trying to display every character on the image sheet as separate images. That you could then freely zoom in with the pixelated effect.

The idea that I have is to turn them into Base64 or something and make the modifications there or before. And at the end, display the final result back into an image, as base64 or blob or other. And that all with the help of JavaScript.

But how would it work? What would the actual process be?

A good solution I came up with was this https://jsfiddle.net/1rmya08u/

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the `canvas` element. Here's the solution:

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="64" height="64"></canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; // For pixelated drawing

var sheet = new Image();
sheet.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxJOx.png";
sheet.onload = function () {
  var sx = 0;
  var sy = 0;
  var sWidth = 16;
  var sHeight = 16;
  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;
  var dWidth = 64;
  var dHeight = 64;

  ctx.drawImage(sheet, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
};
```

We're taking a 16x16 sample from the image sheet and rendering it at 64x64. For a better understanding of these arguments, take a look at the [reference for ctx.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

And finally, you can get the result as an image with `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`

Comment: While looking at a GitHub repository I found the same solution as well and just wanted to include it here as an answer. I wonder though if there are other ways to do this with JavaScript, or if this is one of the only ways.